# commit not visible on github after push

Tags: git, github

I've got strange issue today. So I have forked repository on my github account. I cloned it and introduced some changes. When I pushed it, everything was fine, but respective subpage on github is silent about my change. Now when I take pull or push on that local branch it says everything is up-to-date.

```
git checkout mychange
Switched to branch 'mychange'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/mychange'.
```

I've checked whether I work on detached HEAD, but everything is fine.

What's more, I cloned that repo in a different folder, then printed the logs and my commit indeed is there! So why I can't see it on github?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** If you really dont have any errors, that seems like you are pushing in wrong repository. Run  `git remote -v` and ensure that `origin` is that repository you are checking on github.

**2.** And to ensure that you actually pushed your changes in the remote repo run:

```
git diff mychange origin/mychange
git fetch origin
git diff mychange origin/mychange
```

Diff should prints nothing both times.

**3.** If all of this seems alright, then be sure, that you checked the branch by a filter on the commits tab (https://github.com/USER-NAME/REPO-NAME/commits/BRANCH-NAME), because you could just dont noticed it, like this:
[image: Commits page with filled branch filter field]

**4.** If you still see different commits in the remote repo throught git bash and on the site, then try to change remote head of the branch somehow.
For example you can amend your last commit and then do forced push.

I think, that there (on GitHub) are some hooks to update web representation. And they didn't worked for some reason in your last push to this branch. So another push will run it.

*In that particular case, that was a solution.*

Comment: I doublechecked that as you suggested but it's okay. Remember that I cloned the repository to a directly from github to another folder, where I could see my commit in logs but not on website.

Comment: I've checked the output of your commands as well. The same commit everywhere.

Comment: Is your repo public? Can you give us a repo link and your commit hash?

Comment: And the branch name too

Comment: Can you joint to freenode irc? https://webchat.freenode.net/ write to Ovsyanka plz.

Comment: `origin https://github.com/dokato/scikit-learn.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/dokato/scikit-learn.git (push)` looks fine for me. And yes I can, channel?

Comment: No matter, You just need to write `/query Ovsyanka hi` in bottom editbox

Comment: what is the output of `git push origin adaboost_zerodiverror`?

Comment: And then of `git push -f origin adaboost_zerodiverror`? (full output plz)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you select your `mychange` branch. Default is `master` branch.

[image]

---

Go to https://github.com/USER-NAME/REPO-NAME/tree/mychange

Replace `USER_NAME`, `REPO-NAME` with exact value. In URL `mychange` is your branch name.

**Edit:**

You mentioned in comment that you have no difference with `git diff origin/mychange`, so seems like your push was successful.

Check the commit lists of `origin/mychange` by `git log origin/mychange` and see if your last commit exist or not!

Comment: I'm checking `mychange` branch on github. Nothing there.

Comment: `git fetch`. What is the output of `get diff origin/mychange`?

Comment: being on local branch `mychange` command `git diff origin/mychange` gives empty line

Comment: Ok. Seems your changes are pushed as no changes are found. What is the output of `git log origin/mychange`? Do you see your last commit here ?

Comment: If your repo is public then Can you attach your Repo link in OP?

Comment: yes, I can see my commit in origin logs. I started thinking that maybe it's something with browser cache, but tried on different computer and it wasn't there as well.